# Apply st_bbox() for each feature in sf

Tags: r, geometry, extents, sf

I have a set of polygons and I want to find the bbox for each polygon using sf.
With `st_bbox` I obtain the bbox for the whole set of features but I want to obtain bbox for each feature.

I try to use `group_by()` but the output is always the same.

```r
library(sf)

g <-  st_sfc(st_point(1:2), st_point(3:4)) %>% st_buffer(dist = 1)
s <-  st_sf(a=3:4, g)
s %>% group_by(a) %>% st_bbox()%>% st_as_sfc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
g0 <- st_sfc(st_point(1:2), st_point(3:4))  
g1 <- st_buffer(g0, dist=1)  
is.list(g1)  
f <- function(x) st_as_sfc(st_bbox(x))    
bbs <- do.call("c", lapply(g1, f))  
bbs  
plot(bbs)  
plot(g1, add = T)
```

I take solution from here https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1179

Answer (score 0):

an alternative could be:

```
library(sf)

data <- st_read('input_vector.shp')

for (i in 1:(nrow(data))) {
    print(st_bbox(data[i,]))
}
```